# How to View Detailed Information of a Specific Agent in AnyLogic Model at Runtime?

Tags: anylogic

In my AnyLogic simulation model, I have a group of agents, each with distinct characteristics. While I understand that it's possible to view the parameters of these agents by clicking on the agent group during runtime, I'm interested in knowing how to access detailed parameters and state information of a specific agent within this group.

How can I set up my model so that clicking on an individual agent displays its detailed parameters and state information? I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this.

For instance, if my agent group consists of two vehicles, how can I view a specific vehicle? I'm seeking a method that allows me to select and inspect the details of an individual vehicle within the simulation.

I appreciate any advice or instructions you can provide.
[logic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cdWM.png)
[3D view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Gqc.png)

Comment: Pls study all step-by-step tutorials first, they demo this and many other things. Also check the `ViewArea` block in the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/viewarea.html

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance; it has been greatly beneficial to my learning.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.

I suggest building your own custom pop-up UI element that is shown once you click on the agent.

In this element, you can then add whatever information you need.

see example below

[image]

Each element is set to dynamically show something important to me to view at runtime using the dynamic value property of the text.

[image]

I then group all the elements into a single group, and set the visibility to false.

Then, on my agent's animation object, I set the on click code to change the group's visibility to the inverse of what it is currently.

That way, clicking on the agent alternates the visibility of the popup.

[image]

You can view how this was used in practice in this presentation at the AnyLogic conference - https://youtu.be/KM-mz3Ya1a0?si=Cx9LJVppVE_3nm5C

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance; it has been greatly beneficial to my learning.

Comment: Thank you. If you feel that my response answered your questions be sure to mark it as such and upvote if you think it worthly @waynewick